# Select Data from PHPDatabase: Message-like Algorithm

Tags: php, mysql

User 1 and 2 has a form.

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
  <input type = "text" name = "msg" placeholder = "message...">
  <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "send">
</form>
```

And I have this table on my database:

```
AccID  |  FROM  | TO  |  MESSAGE
```

The PHP Code that sends this message to the database is quite simple too:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (from, to, message) VALUES ('$userid','$to','$msg')";
$q = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Now if user1 would send "Hello User 2!", it would then register to the database with user1's id to the `from` table, and then user2's id to the `to` right? And if user2 sends, user2's id would be in the `from` and user1's on the `to`.

Given this sample Table now: (Let's say other users starts to message too)

```
AccID  |  FROM  |  TO  | MESSAGE 
1         user1   user2    hello user2!
2         user2   user1    hi watsup?
3         user3   user1    hi user1
4         user4   user3    hey user3
```

How can I select and view user1 and user 2's conversation only?
I tried `"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from,to = 'user1' AND from,to = 'user2'";` but somehow didn't worked.

Comment: you're using 2 mysql reserved words if you weren't aware of that, so I doubt what you posted as shown for the INSERT works on its own

Comment: @Fred-ii- What do you mean?

Comment: Consult the reference manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: try "select * from messages where `from` in ('user1','user2') and `to` in ('user1','user2');"

Comment: @Fred-ii- I still don't get it :(

Comment: `from` and `to` are mysql reserved words and interpreter can confuse them,  so 
1) try to avoid mysql reserved words as table / column names
2) it's good to enclose those column names with " ` " (not " ' " ) even if it works without the enclosure.

Comment: @JPKim You mean like this? `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from = ('user1','user2') AND to = ('user1','user2')";` ?

Comment: @JPKim Yes I get it,, i'd actually changed mine like "from" to "fromid" thanks!

Comment: @Dranreb , fyi, use "IN" instead of "=" for you are comparing multiple  values to the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query. `Assuming that AccID is unique` for each record, I have used `ORDER BY AccID` so that messages can be fetched in their insertion order.

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE (`from` = 'user1' AND `to` = 'user2') OR (`from` = 'user2' AND `to` = 'user1')
ORDER BY AccID;
```

Another option (For Better performance):

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE `from` IN ('user1','user2') AND `to` IN ('user1','user2')
ORDER BY AccID;
```

**NOTE:** `from` and `to` are SQL reserved keywords. So kindly avoid using them as names of columns in your table.

Instead try using some meaningful names that do not clash with any reserved keywords and also increase readability, for example, sent_from_user, sent_to_user.

Comment: Could I also use this within an IF statement? Like `if(user1 IN ('user1','user2')){`

Comment: user1 is value. Not your column name. You can't use in that way. And `IN` would be best option when comparing with multiple values.